# Why is react-i18next using Suspense by default even though it's experimental

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

We are using react-i18next in production and everywhere in the documentation it's recommended that we use it with React's Suspense. The problem is React documentation clearly states that the only stable use of Suspense is when it's used together with React.lazy. All other uses of Suspense are experimental and require you to enable Concurrent mode which is also experimental. Is react-i18next using React.lazy internally or is it relying on the developers to enable experimental features?